# How to find duplicate of a question?

Tags: support, duplicates

One or two questions of mine are correctly marked as duplicate in the community.

How can I find the duplicate of my question before I post the question in the site?

Because it is not easy to find similar questions by simple search in the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's really just mostly searching. You can limit your search using tags—just include the tag name, surrounded by brackets, when doing your search (e.g., "[[phd] grades](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bphd%5D+grades)"). That helps limit the search. You can also use "[is:question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bphd%5D+grades+is%3Aquestion)" to only search only questions (e.g., not answers). Past that, it's just making sure you use good search terms. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Note that when you start typing a new question title into the "[Ask a Question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" box, it lists some possible duplicates immediately underneath. Read through these questions to make sure you are not asking a duplicate.

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right, I did not pay attention to that list.

Answer (score 3):

This is too long for a comment ...

Before asking a question it is best to have a quick search for similar questions. If you don't find a match and then ask a question that eventually gets closed as a duplicate, it is not an awful thing. While most closed questions eventually get deleted, duplicates are special and tend to get left on the system. This means that a duplicate question makes finding the original question a little easier for the next person.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the correct answers, I have to agree that the search features of StackExchange are not exactly inspiring. I myself often think "I think we have seen this question before", but when I go and look for it, I can't find any duplicate. It always seems to me that I am only able to find a duplicate if I remember at least some words of the question title.

As such, for a new user, I would propose to do a quick search, and if you can't find a clear answer, just go ahead and ask your question. If it is closed as a duplicate, you at least know where to look. Always remember that a question being closed is not an insult, and does not cost you reputation on the site.